# Moments of a symmetric stable distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

If ${X_n}$ are iid with characteristic function $\exp\left(-c|t|^\alpha\right)$ then when are the moments $|X|^p $  , where $p$ is a real , defined ? If possible , can we evaluate them ?

Comment: Look up inverse Fourier transform/how to get density out of characteristic function and do the calculation.

Comment: I am aware of the inversion formula , but can we use any other result if we just want to show existence of moment without calculating ? If $p$ were a natural number , we could have looked at the no. of times the cf is differentiable which , in turn , would have given some information about the moments .

Comment: If you know what facts hold for $p\in \mathbb{N}$ I'm not aware of anything that could be helpful apart from that for $p<q$ $L_p\subset L_q$

Comment: I've managed to prove that $p^\text{th}$ moment exists for $p<\alpha$. Would you like to see that?

Comment: Yes , sure ! I would definitely like to see that .

Answer (score 2):

I will show that $p^{th}$ moment exists for $p<\alpha$.
$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$

1. Recall/prove following inequality that is being used in the proof of Levy-Cramer's/Levy's continuity Theorem
   $$\P(|X|\geq t) \leq At\int_{-1/t}^{1/t}(1-\varphi(s))ds$$
2. Use it to bound tails
   $$
   \P(|X|\geq t) \leq At\int_{-1/t}^{1/t}(1-e^{-c|s|^\alpha})ds \leq 2At\int_0^{1/t}cs^\alpha ds = \frac{2Ac}{\alpha+1}t^{-\alpha} =Bt^{-\alpha}
   $$
3. Use derived bound to show that $p^{th}$ moment exists
   $$
    \E|X|^p = \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\P(|X|\geq t)dt < \infty \Leftrightarrow\\ 
   \int_1^\infty pt^{p-1}\P(|X|\geq t)dt < pB\int_1^\infty t^{p-1}t^{-\alpha}dt < \infty \Leftrightarrow p-1-\alpha < -1 \Leftrightarrow \\ p < \alpha
   $$

Comment: I have come to know , as a fact  , that the p-th moment will blow up for $p \geq \alpha$ , but I do not know the proof .